# How do i make the camera rotate about the object using the mouse or keyboard in the game engine?

Tags: game-engine, camera, constraints

please how do i get the camera to use the character as the pivot point while  rotating with the keyboard or mouse? I also want the camera's view still centered on the character like in a normal animation. I tried the pivot constraint,change of the universal pivot found beside the view-port shading and even tried changing the camera's origin point. The first two worked fine in the editor window but not while playing the game while the third one didn't work at all.

Comment: Generally you have to apply the controls to the character object itself, then parent the camera to the character object.

Comment: this video may help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMr4zSgq_4Q

Answer (score -1):

Press Shift + F on keyboard
Once you press shift+F on keyboard u can move the camera where you want with the arrow up down front back and A S W D key like games

Comment: This does not work for the game engine